# Freemarker and hashmap. How do I get key-value

Tags: java, html, freemarker

I have a hash map as below

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("one", "1");
map.put("two", "2");
map.put("three", "3");

Map root = new HashMap();
root.put("hello", map);
```

My Freemarker template is:

```
<html><body>
    <#list hello?keys as key> 
        ${key} = ${hello[key]} 
    </#list> 
</body></html>
```

The goal is to display key-value pair in the HTML that I'm generating. Please help me to do it. Thanks!

Comment: What's displayed? Where is the error?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Code:**

```
Map root = new HashMap();
HashMap<String, String> test1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
test1.put("one", "1");
test1.put("two", "2");
test1.put("three", "3");
root.put("hello", test1);


Configuration cfg = new Configuration(); // Create configuration
Template template = cfg.getTemplate("test.ftl"); // Filename of your template

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); // So you can use the output as String
template.process(root, sw); // process the template to output

System.out.println(sw); // eg. output your result
```

**Template:**

```
<body>
<#list hello?keys as key> 
    ${key} = ${hello[key]} 
</#list> 
</body>
```

**Output:**

```
<body>
    two = 2 
    one = 1 
    three = 3 
</body>
```

Comment: Since 2.3.25 there's a better way; see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38273478/606679

Answer (score 26):

Since 2.3.25, you can do this:

```
<body>
<#list hello as key, value> 
    ${key} = ${value} 
</#list> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Before 2.3.25, in case of keys containing objects, you can try to use

```
<#assign key_list = map?keys/>
<#assign value_list = map?values/>
<#list key_list as key>
  ...
  <#assign seq_index = key_list?seq_index_of(key) />
  <#assign key_value = value_list[seq_index]/>
  ...
     //Use the ${key_value}
  ...
</#list>
```

Comment: This is the ugliest solution ever, nevertheless, it works fine when I had a LONG as a keys in hash and I needed to preserve and use the key later

Comment: Works also fine if key and value are more complex java beans, not just strings :)

Answer (score 4):

Use a map that preserves the insertion order of the key-value pairs: LinkedHashMap

Comment: This answer is assuming that the problem is that the output is not in insertion order.   I'm not sure if that is true.