# Freemarker - access value at a particular key in map

Tags: java, freemarker

I have `Map` variable in my Freemarker template. How can I fetch a value at a particular key in the map, as we do in Java (`map.get(<key>)`).

I know how to iterate through keys and values of a map in a FTL. But I want a solution without iteration, on the lines of Java `get()` method of `Map` interface.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821329/freemarker-and-hashmap-how-do-i-get-key-value

Comment: Ehm, did you read [the manual](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_var)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`map[dynamicKey]` or `map.staticKey` if the key is a string. Due to historical limitations, if the key isn't a string, `map?api.get(nonStringKey)`.