# How to get value from HashMap in Freemarker template?

Tags: java, hashmap, freemarker

How to get value from HashMap in Freemarker template if `Map<String, MyObject>`?

I have Data Structure ex.: `Map<String, List<MyObject>>`, how to get all values from this Map in Freemarker Template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the [documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#ref.directive.list) on how to iterate over collections/sequences.

```
<#list products as k, v>
    <p>${v}: ${v}
</#list>
```

If you want to iterate over the values only then use:

```
<#list myHash?values as v>
    ${v}
</#list>
```

The documentation link can be found [here](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html#ref_builtin_values).

Also check the answers from these questions, they might help you: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821329/freemarker-and-hashmap-how-do-i-get-key-value/38273478#38273478) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248560/freemarker-access-value-at-a-particular-key-in-map).

Update:

The previous examples the variable v is a list since your map is `Map<String, List<Object>>`. If you want to access each item in the list you need a double iteration.

```
<#list myMap as k, v>
    <#list v as x>
        <p> ${x}
    </#list>
</#list>
```

Comment: This solution works if my Data Structure has only String (`Map<String, String>`)

Comment: Updated then answer. I hope it helps

Comment: You can refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821329/freemarker-and-hashmap-how-do-i-get-key-value