# Java freemarker access hash value by unique key

Tags: java, xml, freemarker

I have a hash map as below

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("one", "#define");
map.put("two", "ABC");
map.put("three", "3");

Map root = new HashMap();
root.put("hello", map);
```

How can I access only one special key in Freemarker, let say “two”?

```
<#list hello?keys as key> 
    ${key} = ${hello[“two”]}  
</#list>
```

I want to generate:

```
{key-value-1} {key-value-2} {key-value-3}
#define ABC  3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Freemarker and hashmap. How do I get key-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821329/freemarker-and-hashmap-how-do-i-get-key-value)

Comment: Not really. In this example all three key - value pairs are generated. However, I want to generate the each kay - value pair separately.

Comment: I would start with trying normal double quotes in your freemarker template, instead of fancy quotes.

Comment: You can access the value under a specific key like `hello.two`, or `hello["has space"]`. But then, in the desired output that you show, you only print the `hello?values`, so I'm not sure what do you want to achieve.