# Freemarker: Model based on properties

Tags: java, freemarker

If I understand Freemarker's MapModel correctly, then an expression like

```
<#if property.name == "true">
```

would look into the map, finds an object "property". And, if that's a map, looks up the value "name" in the inner map.

Now, assume, that my Map is a Properties object, and I would want "property.name to be evaluated a s the value of property "property.name"? Is that possibly? How?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Freemarker and hashmap. How do I get key-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821329/freemarker-and-hashmap-how-do-i-get-key-value)

Comment: Note that if `property.name` is a string that's either `"true"`, or `"false"`, then `<#if property.name?boolean>` is nicer.

Answer (score 0):

It should just work the same with `java.util.Properties`, because that implements `java.util.Map`.